# Wyam - how do I order content in a pipeline?

Tags: wyam

I try out to generate a static HTML file from different .md files with Wyam, but my pipelines dont create the content in the right order.

I'm set the orderby and thenby statement of the file attributes to get the parts of my HTML result in the order of my input folder structure.

My input folder has the following structure:

```
Input
│   help.md
│
├───1_Intro
│       1_general.md
│
├───2_examples
│       1_general.md
│       2_examples.md
│
└───3_appendix
        1_glossar.md
        2_sources.md
```

So here is my wyam.conf file for with my pipeline:

```
// Load Wyam Modules
#n Wyam.Html 
#n Wyam.Markdown
#n Wyam.Yaml

// Setting culture
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-EN");

    Pipelines.Add("Help",
    ReadFiles("help.md"),
        Append(
            ReadFiles("*/{*,!help}.md"),
            OrderBy((d, c) => d["SourceFileBase"]).ThenBy((d, c) => d["SourceFileName"]),
            FrontMatter(Yaml()),    
            Markdown()
            ),
        FrontMatter(Yaml()),
        Markdown(),
        Combine(),
        WriteFiles(".html")
    ).WithProcessDocumentsOnce();
```

I was expecting to get a HTML file were the content of my .md files is in order like this:

```
1.1 General
Lorem ipsum...
2.1 About my Examples
...
2.2 Examples
...
3.1 Glossar
...
3.2 Sources
...
```

But after running Wyam with my pipeline I get results like this:

```
3.1 Glossar
Lorem ipsum...
2.1 About my Examples
...
2.2 Examples
...
3.2 Sources
...
1.1 General
...
```

Every time I run Wyam with my pipeline I got different results, some are in the order I wanted to create, but the most results look utterly random to me.

Could someone tell me what I'm doring wrong?